# FTP getting timed out and not working

Tags: ftp

I installed vsftpd and proFTPD and none of them are working.

when I do ftp myserverIP then it says timed out on my VPS command line...

I don't know how to set up user and password as well..

When I do ftp localhost , then it asks for username and password, and I don't know what is username and password..

My OS: Ubuntu 14.04

I installed FTP server using 
sudo apt-get install proftpd
sudo apt-get install vsftpd

And I don't know how to show config files.
ServerName                      "servername"
ServerType                      standalone
DeferWelcome                    off

MultilineRFC2228                on
DefaultServer                   on
ShowSymlinks                    on

TimeoutNoTransfer               600
TimeoutStalled                  600
TimeoutIdle                     1200

DisplayLogin                    welcome.msg
DisplayChdir                    .message true
ListOptions                     "-l"
 it looks something like that

Comment: You may add information so that we can help you. What is your OS? How did you install you FTP server? What do your config files looks like? When installing any piece of software on a server, you MUST configure it (saying you use default config is a way of configuring it).

Comment: Can you edit your question to add the output from the commands `sudo netstat -tlnp` and `sudo iptables -L -nv`?  It might also be worth looking in the vsftpd and ProFTPD logs and adding any errors you find to your question.

Comment: username and password are synonyms for login and... password

Comment: did you look at http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/ConfigFile.html ?